# How to create child processes in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a daily task to do the update of 2000 employees about their working hours. The problem that i have that the update is taking way to long for my company and i need to improve the update time. I am doing it this way and i need to create child processes so i can improve time. i have tried to work it out with mongodb $skip and $limit but can't find out a way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
function updateDb(timesheet, doneCallback) {
                    var options = {
                        upsert: true,
                        new: true
                    };

                    TimeSheet.findOneAndUpdate({
                        $and: [
                            {ccms_id: timesheet.ccms_id},
                            {date: timesheet.date}
                        ]
                    }, timesheet, options, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            logger.error(err);
                        }
                        logger.info(`Saving timesheet in DB for ${timesheet.name}`);
                        socket.emit('log',`Saving timesheet in DB for ${timesheet.name}`);
                        return doneCallback(err, result);
                    });
                }
```

Comment: please describe better your question.

Comment: how much records you have and what type of operation you are making? 2.000 records it's not hard for MongoDB. Can you explain what you means for "to long"?

Comment: @DanieleTassone it takes me 20 min for 2000 records.

Comment: what type of operation you are making for the Update? Did you create an Index? There are a lot of missing informations. Please update your question otherwise is not possibile to understand what you need.

Comment: @DanieleTassone What do u need ?

Comment: what type of operation you are making for the Update? Did you create an Index?

Comment: @DanieleTassone no i didnt create an index. I am using socket.io- to receive and send data

Comment: so MongoDB take 20 seconds to made the read-query or the update-query?

Comment: it takes 100 sec per items. Read query takes 5-10 sec. Update query takes the rest of time

Comment: what type of operation you are making for the Update? (i just counted i asked you 3 time that question) :-)

Comment: @DanieleTassone Cant understand what you are saying. Users selects date of work and i do the update based on employee data. So practically i take the employee data that are saved automatically in a database i read them and write them in a new database containing only the items i need. Please specify what u mean with what type of operation you are making for the Update

Comment: start by creating one index for "ccms_id" and "date" this will help you made the read query more fast.

Comment: @DanieleTassone Sorry but how can i do it as i am new in mongo. I got this job from someone else

Comment: yourCollection.ensureIndex({"ccms_id": 1, "date": 1}, depending the Sort order you want to achieve you should specify 1 or -1 (descending)

Comment: ok so where do i put this before the findoneandupdate? @DanieleTassone

Comment: You should put this code before; when the index is created is not necessary to call the index creation another time. Would be better for you to read a bit MongoDB before start to work on it. Otherwise will be really difficult for you to understand how to move forward. I feel like I'm teaching you how to drive a car but you have never see a Car before.